# Dynamically add CORS Mappings to Rest Controller at runtime

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-boot, cors

Hi! I am a beginner in Spring Boot. I have a simple Java Spring Boot Application which uses a Rest Controller. Some of the controller's endpoints are exposed to CORS requests. I've found out that it is possible to allow CORS requests by adding @CrossOrigin(origins ="..") annotations above the methods. 

My problem is that I don't know all the origins at the moment and will have to add some of them later during the runtime of my Spring Boot Application.

Is it possible to have a method to manually add new origin-addresses to some endpoints of my Rest Controller? E.g. to have an endpoint in my Rest Controller that allows a particular user (e.g.Admin) to add new cors-origins to a rest endpoint? If yes: Please give a simple example.

Comment: Have you thought about using a filter to externalize this cross cutting concern?

Comment: Did you solved the problem? If yes, can you answer it, please?

Answer (score 3):

I think this is possible by implementing your own `org.springframework.web.cors.CorsProcessor`. Look at he implementation of `org.springframework.web.filter.CorsFilter` which can get configured with your custom `CorsProcessor` via method `public void setCorsProcessor(CorsProcessor processor)`.

I woulod then suggest to implement your own `CorsProcessor` and handle in the method `process` your custom rules.

Or another option is to set your own `CorsConfigurationSource` in your Spring Security Config. e.g.

```
@Override
 protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.cors().configurationSource(new CustomConfigSource());
}
```

The `CorsConfigurationSource` offers a method `CorsConfiguration getCorsConfiguration(HttpServletRequest request);` in which you can handle your specific CORS  Handling.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Unfortunately I am a bit confused. Where should I put my own CorsProcessor and how should I call the getCorsConfiguration(HttpServletRequest req) method? I don't have parameters of type HttpServletRequest anywhere in my Rest Controller. 

...as you can see, I am a real beginner

Comment: I would suggest to take the 2nd option I offered. Add your own `ConfigurationSource` to your cors config in your Spring Security Config. The Framework will then call for each request the method `getCorsConfiguration(HttpServletRequest request);`

Answer (score 1):

```
@Override
protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {
    response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");

    if (request.getHeader("Access-Control-Request-Method") != null && "OPTIONS".equals(request.getMethod())) {
        LOG.trace("Sending Header....");
        // CORS "pre-flight" request
        response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE");

        response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type");
        response.addHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "1");
    }

    filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
}
```

please use the filter [cros_filter](https://gist.github.com/zeroows/80bbe076d15cb8a4f0ad)

Answer (score 0):

The following worked for me in Spring 2.4:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.cors.CorsConfiguration;
import org.springframework.web.cors.UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource;
import org.springframework.web.filter.CorsFilter;

@Configuration
public class CorsConfig {

    @Bean
    public CorsFilter corsFilter() {
        final UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        final CorsConfiguration corsConfiguration = new CorsConfiguration();

        final String corsAllowedOrigins = System.getenv("CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS");

        corsConfiguration.setAllowCredentials(true);
        corsConfiguration.setAllowedOrigins(Arrays.asList(corsAllowedOrigins.split(",")));
        corsConfiguration.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList(CorsConfiguration.ALL));
        corsConfiguration.setAllowedHeaders(Arrays.asList(CorsConfiguration.ALL));

        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", corsConfiguration);

        return new CorsFilter(source);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

you can add it to HttpServletResponse res directly by `res.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin","what you want here like http/.....");`

```
@RequestMapping(value="/getbot/{id}", 
       method = RequestMethod.POST,
       headers="Accept=application/json") 
@ResponseBody public String getbot(HttpServletResponse res) { 
          res.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin","*");
          ...
}
```

I have tried that no way to do it with springboot because there is default cors handler will over write your headers,i didnt find a way to stop it
i think we need to write servlet for that springboot we cant do it dynamically