# IntelliJ Idea SpringBoot-Application (Java 19) Allow the device with the front-end aplication to work together with the external back-end application

Tags: spring-boot, intellij-idea, java-19

the question as follows :

I have a hardcoded IP-adress inside of the allowlist of the back-end application.
Everytime the front-end application is running on another device, the front-end has to get permission from the back-end to be used (externally).

How do i do it the best? the goal is to not manually change/allow the front-end device's IP-adress everytime. We do not use a domain name.

I have tried everything i could but i just cannot seem to find an answer.

The hard coded IP-adress inside of the allowlist of the back-end application:
[image]

Comment: Please don't add code as images but rather as code (text surrounded by code tags) that way it is readable. Looking at this the 192.168 is an internal IP range, you can use wildcards for that.

Comment: (in the current config,) You could obtain the "list of url's" from anywhere (db, cloud, file). [This question asks "how to do it dynamically?"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47652895/592355) (no accepted answer, but helpful input(CorsProcessor, CorsConfigurationSource))